# Convert matrix to UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, matrix, uiimage

I need to convert a matrix representing a b/w image to UIImage.

For example:

A matrix like this (just the representation). This image would be the symbol '+'

1 0 1

0 0 0

1 0 1

This matrix represents an image in black and white, where black is 0 and white is 1. I need to convert this matrix to UIImage. In this case width would be 3 and height would be 3

Comment: Isn't the convention to use 1 as white and 0 as black (the opposite of what you have)?

Comment: Post what you have tried. Explain what issue you are having with the code.

Comment: @IanMacDonald yes it's true but I define those numbers. It's OK if black is 1 or 0 for me as long as I know the color value.

Comment: @rmaddy done. When I save the image to see the result, it's empty (all white).

Answer (score 1):

I use this method to create an image for my Game Of Life app. The advantages over drawing to a graphics context is that this is ridiculously fast.

This was all written a long time ago so it's a bit messier than what I might do now but the method would stay the same. For some reasons I defined these outside the method...

```
{
    unsigned int length_in_bytes;
    unsigned char *cells;
    unsigned char *temp_cells;
    unsigned char *changes;
    unsigned char *temp_changes;
    GLubyte *buffer;
    CGImageRef imageRef;
    CGDataProviderRef provider;
    int ar, ag, ab, dr, dg, db;
    float arf, agf, abf, drf, dgf, dbf, blah;
}
```

You won't need all of these for the image.

The method itself...

```
- (UIImage*)imageOfMapWithDeadColor:(UIColor *)deadColor aliveColor:(UIColor *)aliveColor
{
    //translate colours into rgb components
    if ([deadColor isEqual:[UIColor whiteColor]]) {
        dr = dg = db = 255;
    } else if ([deadColor isEqual:[UIColor blackColor]]) {
        dr = dg = db = 0;
    } else {
        [deadColor getRed:&drf green:&dgf blue:&dbf alpha:&blah];

        dr = drf * 255;
        dg = dgf * 255;
        db = dbf * 255;
    }

    if ([aliveColor isEqual:[UIColor whiteColor]]) {
        ar = ag = ab = 255;
    } else if ([aliveColor isEqual:[UIColor blackColor]]) {
        ar = ag = ab = 0;
    } else {
        [aliveColor getRed:&arf green:&agf blue:&abf alpha:&blah];

        ar = arf * 255;
        ag = agf * 255;
        ab = abf * 255;
    }

//    dr = 255, dg = 255, db = 255;
//    ar = 0, ag = 0, ab = 0;

    //create bytes of image from the cell map
    int yRef, cellRef;

    unsigned char *cell_ptr = cells;

    for (int y=0; y<self.height; y++)
    {
        yRef = y * (self.width * 4);

        int x = 0;
        do
        {
            cellRef = yRef + 4 * x;

            if (*cell_ptr & 0x01) {
                //alive colour
                buffer[cellRef] = ar;
                buffer[cellRef + 1] = ag;
                buffer[cellRef + 2] = ab;
                buffer[cellRef + 3] = 255;
            } else {
                //dead colour
                buffer[cellRef] = dr;
                buffer[cellRef + 1] = dg;
                buffer[cellRef + 2] = db;
                buffer[cellRef + 3] = 255;
            }
            cell_ptr++;
        } while (++x < self.width);
    }

    //create image
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // render the byte array into an image ref
    imageRef = CGImageCreate(self.width, self.height, 8, 32, 4 * self.width, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault, provider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    // convert image ref to UIImage
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    //return image
    return image;
}
```

You should be able to adapt this to create an image from your matrix.

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert a matrix to UIImage :

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(lines, columns);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, YES, 0);

for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        // Choose color to draw 
        if ( matrixDraw[i*lines + j] == 1 ) {

            [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];

        } else {

            // Draw black pixel
            [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];            
        }

        // Draw just one pixel in i,j
        UIRectFill(CGRectMake(i, j, 1, 1)); 

    }
}

// Create UIImage with the current context that we have just created
UIImage *imageFinal = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Basically what we are doing is :

1. Create a context with the size of our image
2. Looping for each pixel to see the value. Black is 0 and white is 1. So depends on the value, we set the color.
3. The most important function :

   ```
     UIRectFill(CGRectMake(i,j,1,1));
   ```

This function let us to fill a pixel in the i,j position with width and height (1 both cases for fill one single pixel)

4. Finally we create an UIImage with the current context and we call to finish the image context.

Hope it helps someone!